# Finding the derivative of an inverse function from first principles

Tags: calculus

I have tried using the definition of derivative by

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f^{-1}\left(x + h\right) - f^{-1}\left(x\right)}{h} $$

but that is not correct. (it was marked wrong).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that is not correct? I'd say it is, assuming the limit exists.

Comment: Probably, they wanted to express $(f^{-1})'$ using $f'$ and $f$..

Comment: @berci I think you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct so far, but you should go on, somehow introducing the definition of $f'$.

Briefly, it goes like $t:=f^{-1}(x+h)-f^{-1}(x)$, we need that $t\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, and then consider $y:=f^{-1}(x)$ and
$$ h = (x+h)-x = f(y+t) -f(y) $$

Comment: thanks, I will try to work that path out.